# Dynamic Where Class Using 'CASE' will affect performance

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table called Employee. 
Fields are

1.EmployeeId, 
2.Name, 
3.Salary, 
4.Address

I need to write a procedure that will fetch all the employee details. The where clause of this procedure is dynamic. I can able to write a dynamic query do fetch the details. But i recently explore the below format query.

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
WHERE 1=1
AND EmployeeId = CASE WHEN @EmployeeId IS NULL  OR LEN(@EmployeeId) =0  THEN EmployeeId ELSE  @EmployeeId END
AND Name = CASE WHEN @Name IS NULL  OR LEN(@Name) =0  THEN Name ELSE  @Name END
...
...
ORDER BY Name ASC
```

@EmployeeId , @name are coming from application

Can any tell me this will make any performance impact over a dynamic query? or Which one is better performance?

The where clause condition is dynamic. This is not strict with 2 condition. Some times its 1 or 3 or 4 or 0

Sorry for any typo-errors

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I removed the database tags you added as you clearly aren't using both MySQL and SQL server. Please only add back the tag for the RDMS you are actually using.

Comment: From where do `EmployeeID` and `Name` come? Are they columns in your table `Employee`?

Comment: You could create an `if`/`then`/`else` tree with the 16 possible variations of search conditions and execute the appropriate query. Or assemble a stored procedure name based on the search criteria and execute the SP. Either way allows you to use a pre-compiled "optimal" query. Aside: Do you really intend to examine all columns and reject any row that contains a `NULL` value? If not, you would want something like `case when ( @Name is NULL or @Name = '' ) or ( Name = @Name ) then 1 else 0 end = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this was the data you are working with:

```
-- sample data
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.employee (EmployeeId int, Name varchar(100));
INSERT dbo.employee
SELECT TOP (100)
  ABS(checksum(newid())%10)+1, 
  CASE abs(checksum(newid())%3)+1 WHEN 1 THEN 'Peter' WHEN 2 THEN 'Paul' ELSE 'Mary' END 
  + ' ' +
  CASE abs(checksum(newid())%3)+1 WHEN 1 THEN 'Smith' WHEN 2 THEN 'Jones' ELSE 'White' END
FROM sys.all_columns;

-- A good covering index 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nc_employee ON dbo.employee (EmployeeId, Name);
```

First note that you can get the exact same results and execution plan with this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.employee
WHERE (EmployeeId = @EmployeeId OR NULLIF(LEN(@EmployeeId),0) IS NULL)
AND   (Name       = @Name       OR NULLIF(LEN(@Name),0)       IS NULL)
```

Presuming there is a usable index present - your query (or the query above) will create a basic execution plan consisting of an index seek or index Scan, and a SELECT operator. A scan if you run the query as-is, a seek if you include OPTION (RECOMPILE) at the end of either query... An index seek is much better than a scan.

An alternative to using the aforementioned OPTION (RECOMPILE) hint to get an index seek would be to use Dynamic SQL as shown below.

```
DECLARE @EmployeeId int    = 5,
        @Name varchar(100) = 'Peter White';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2000) = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.employee';
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@EmployeeId int, @Name varchar(100)';

SET @sql += 
CASE 
  WHEN (NULLIF(LEN(@EmployeeId),0) IS NOT NULL AND NULLIF(LEN(@Name),0) IS NOT NULL)
    THEN ' WHERE EmployeeId = @EmployeeId AND Name = @Name;'
  WHEN (NULLIF(LEN(@EmployeeId),0) IS NULL AND NULLIF(LEN(@Name),0) IS NOT NULL)
    THEN ' WHERE Name = @Name;'
  WHEN (NULLIF(LEN(@EmployeeId),0) IS NOT NULL AND NULLIF(LEN(@Name),0) IS NULL)
    THEN ' WHERE EmployeeId = @EmployeeId;'
  ELSE ''
END;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @ParmDefinition, @EmployeeId = @EmployeeId, @Name = @Name;
```

Finally, it's worth noting that, for cases where @EmployeeID is NULL or blank but @Name has a value - you will get a scan. If you wanted a seek in those cases you would want another index that looks like this present:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nc_employee2 ON dbo.employee (Name, EmployeeId);
```

Comment: The OP's original query filters out all rows where `EmployeeId` or `Name` is `NULL`. You haven't maintained that functionality, however unintentional it was on the OP's part.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. But my problem is, in the where clause is dynamic. If the where clause contain 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 condition based on the application logic. In this scenario which format will perfect? Some times no condition also will come.